# nested object, array combination

Tags: arrays, object

So I have a dilemma. 
I have the next code

```
  const loc = [
    { location_key: [32, 22, 11], autoassign: 1 },
    { location_key: [41, 42], autoassign: 1 }
  ];
  const bulkConfigs = [
    {
      dataValues: {
        config_key: 100,
      }
    },
    {
      dataValues: {
        config_key: 200,
      }
    }
  ];
```

I need to create an object looking like this:

```
  config_key: here get the config key from from bulkConfigs,
  location_key: here get the location_key,
  autoassign: 1
```

Also I need this object created

```
                config_key: config_key,
                location_key: '',
                autoassign: 1,
```

as many times as they are locations for each config_key, what I mean is in this example from config_key: 200 we will have 2 objects like this one and for config_key: 100 we will have 3 objects like this. I suppose this can be done with reduce ... also bulkConfigs and loc can have more then just 2 objects, but the number will be always the same, like if they are 3 bulkConfigs there will be also 3 loc, but location_key might be different, one can have 7 location_key, other 4, and the last one just 1.

So in other words, the arrys are always the same length and they are always in the same order so they have the same index. Only the location_key can change, and I need the object created as many times as location_key exist.

I have tried a few things, but I don't know when it comes to this stuff .... I just can't do, that's what happens when you start with react and not java script :)

Comment: is this that hard? should I try to use lodash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to do this using lodash, here is my solution, I know it's nested like hell and probably this could be done way easier, but for a newbie is good enough. Feel free to come with more elegant solutions.

If you have a similar problem, here is the solution. 
 A code sandbox so you can play with: 
 https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-field-bdwyi?file=/src/index.js

```
import _ from "lodash";

const locs = [{ location_key: [32, 22, 11] }, { location_key: [41, 42] }];
const bulkConfigs = [
  {
    dataValues: {
      config_key: 100
    }
  },
  {
    dataValues: {
      config_key: 200
    }
  }
];

// map over the array of bulckConfigs and get indexes
const mergedArrays = _.map(bulkConfigs, (bulkConfig, i) => {
  // create the object that we need
  const objectNeed = {
    // flatMap over the locs array to get flat values from objects in it
    location_key: _.flatMap(locs, ({ location_key }, index) => {
      // match the indexs of both arrays
      if (index === i) {
        // return the location_key values for each config
        return location_key;
      } else {
        // compact to remove the undefinded values returned
        return _.compact();
      }
    }),
    config_key: bulkConfig.dataValues.config_key,
    autoassign: 1
  };

  return objectNeed;
});

// now we just need to crate the same object as many locations and use flatMap to flatten the objects
const allObjects = _.flatMap(mergedArrays, mergedArray => {
  const yy = _.map(mergedArray.location_key, location => {
    const zz = {
      location_key: location,
      config_key: mergedArray.config_key,
      autoassign: 1
    };
    return zz;
  });
  return yy;
});

console.log(allObjects);
```

And the more elegant version of it :)

```
const getConfigs = (locEl, index) => {
  return _.map(locEl.location_key, (locationKey) => {
    return {
      location_key: locationKey,
      config_key: bulkConfigs[index].dataValues.config_key,
      autoassign: 1,
    };
  });
};

const configLocations = _.chain(locs)
  .map(getConfigs)
  .flatten()
  .value();

console.log(configLocations);
```